# GCC and Clang not warning on unused exception variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang

Consider the following useless code--specifically, the `int k` in the `catch` clause:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw 0;
    }
    catch(int k)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with g++ (version 8.3.0) and clang++ (8.0.0) with `-Wall -Wextra`, no warnings are emitted despite the unused `k` variable. Visual Studio does warn, which is how I discovered this difference in a project of mine.

Is this a bug in GCC and Clang, or am I misunderstanding the `-Wunused` set of flags?

Comment: It could be intended, similar to how there is no warning on unused named template parameters.

Comment: Have you enabled optimizations?  Sometimes these warning only manifest during optimization.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm None of `-O` `-O1` `-O2` `-O3` changes anything.

Comment: I see "Make sure we mark the catch param as used, otherwise we'll get a warning about an unused ((anonymous)).". If I remove the following line, I do get a warning "warning: unused variable 'k'". The comment is strange, I think it is worth reporting to gcc's bugzilla, unless you can find a previous bug report on the same issue.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Clang

Bug report: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41746

It turns out that clang has the warning [`-Wunused-exception-parameter`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wunused-exception-parameter), although it is not activated by any of the groups `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, or `-Wunused`.

#### GCC

Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90353

As noted in a comment to this question and in the bug report, all catch parameters are always marked as used. This is being investigated in the linked bug report.